# The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in

Tags: c#, .net-5

I'm attempting to seed data for my API. I do have JWT authentication setup as well. I have to remove my original migration of the seeded data in order for the program to work. I found it would be helpful to already have data in the API when users interact with it. I"m just unsure to get the the .HasNoKey set up so I can successfully do a migration.

//Context.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AnimalShelter.Models
{
    public class AnimalShelterContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
    public AnimalShelterContext(DbContextOptions<AnimalShelterContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {   
    }
    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>()
            .HasNoKey()
            .HasData(
                new Animal { AnimalId = 6, Name = "Matilda", Neutered = "Y", Age = 7, Species = "Dog",  Gender = "Female", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-08-01,")},
                new Animal { AnimalId = 2, Name = "Rexie", Neutered = "Y", Age = 10, Species = "Dog",  Gender = "Female", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-01,")},
                new Animal { AnimalId = 3, Name = "Matilda", Neutered = "N", Age = 2, Species = "Cat",  Gender = "Female", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-03-01,")},
                new Animal { AnimalId = 4, Name = "Pip", Neutered = "Y", Age = 4, Species = "Bird",  Gender = "Male", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-07-01,")},
                new Animal { AnimalId = 5, Name = "Bartholomew", Neutered = "N", Age = 22, Species = "Cat",  Gender = "Male", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-06-01,")}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

//Terminal message

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add "data seed"
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Internal.MySqlModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnModelCreating you may declare the HasNoKey(). You declare this if you want to configure your specific entity/table with no keys.

In this example we declare the target schema by using the HasDefaultSchema of your entity/table then use the Entity to specify your target table then use the HasNoKey().

[image: Kindly check this image for your reference.]

Goodluck and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); //new line of code
This is a much simpler solution without using .hasNoKey

```
namespace AnimalShelter.Models
{
    public class AnimalShelterContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
    public AnimalShelterContext(DbContextOptions<AnimalShelterContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {   
    }
    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); //new line of code
            modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>()
                        // would be great to be able to seed data
                        // .HasNoKey()
            .HasData(
                new Animal { AnimalId = 6, Name = "Matilda", Neutered = "Y", Age = 7, Species = "Dog",  Gender = "Female", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-08-01,")},
                new Animal { AnimalId = 2, Name = "Rexie", Neutered = "Y", Age = 10, Species = "Dog",  Gender = "Female", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-02-01,")},
                new Animal { AnimalId = 3, Name = "Matilda", Neutered = "N", Age = 2, Species = "Cat",  Gender = "Female", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-03-01,")},
                new Animal { AnimalId = 4, Name = "Pip", Neutered = "Y", Age = 4, Species = "Bird",  Gender = "Male", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-07-01,")},
                new Animal { AnimalId = 5, Name = "Bartholomew", Neutered = "N", Age = 22, Species = "Cat",  Gender = "Male", DateAdd = DateTime.Parse("2022-06-01,")}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just that `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); //new line of code` is the one to fix the issue. Not required to add `HasNoKey()`, because you are using the identity Framework. I don't understand why someone downvoted the answer.